# How can I split a text file into multiple text files using python?

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains the following contents. I want to split this file into multiple files (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt...). Each a new output file will be as the following. The code I tried doesn't split the input file properly. How can I split the input file into multiple files?

**My code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    a1=[]
    a2=[]
    a3=[]
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip() or line.startswith('A') or line.startswith('$$'): continue
        row = line.split()
        a1.append(str(row[0]))
        a2.append(float(row[1]))
        a3.append(float(row[2]))
f = open('1.txt','a')
f = open('2.txt','a')
f = open('3.txt','a')
f.write(str(a1)) 
f.close()
```

**Input file:**

```
A
x
k
..
$$

A
z
m
..
$$

A
B
l
..
$$
```

**Desired output 1.txt**

```
A
x
k
..
$$
```

**Desired output 2.txt**

```
A
z
m
..
$$
```

**Desired output 3.txt**

```
A
B
l
..
$$
```

Comment: i would use [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this...

Comment: Is `$$` the delimiter?

Comment: @pzp, I don't think it's the delimiter since it's included in the desired output. Rather, the extra line-break would be the delimiter here.

Comment: `$$` is a line in the input file. It should be written in each output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) function:

```
import re

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

found = re.findall(r'\n*(A.*?\n\$\$)\n*', data, re.M | re.S)

[open(str(i)+'.txt', 'w').write(found[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(found)+1)]
```

Minimalistic approach *for the first 3 occurrences*:

```
import re

found = re.findall(r'\n*(A.*?\n\$\$)\n*', open('input.txt', 'r').read(), re.M | re.S)

[open(str(found.index(f)+1)+'.txt', 'w').write(f) for f in found[:3]]
```

Some explanations:

```
found = re.findall(r'\n*(A.*?\n\$\$)\n*', data, re.M | re.S)
```

will find all occurrences matching the specified RegEx and will put them into the **list**, called `found`

```
[open(str(found.index(f)+1)+'.txt', 'w').write(f) for f in found]
```

iterate (using list comprehensions) through all elements belonging to `found` list and for each element create text file (which is called like "`index of the element + 1`.txt") and write that element (occurrence) to that file.

Another version, without RegEx's:

```
blocks_to_read = 3
blk_begin = 'A'
blk_end = '$$'

with open('35916503.txt', 'r') as f:
    fn = 1
    data = []
    write_block = False
    for line in f:
        if fn > blocks_to_read:
            break 
        line = line.strip()
        if line == blk_begin:
            write_block = True
        if write_block:
            data.append(line)
        if line == blk_end:
            write_block = False
            with open(str(fn) + '.txt', 'w') as fout:
                fout.write('\n'.join(data))
                data = []
            fn += 1
```

PS i, personally, don't like this version and i would use the one using RegEx

Comment: The regular expression you used is too restrictive. We can't say for sure that that format will hold for all inputs.

Comment: @ChuckLoganLim, i think OP might have '\n's in text-blocks

Comment: @MaxU Your code works properly. Can you please explain what each line does? And I think you can write another code without re.findall() function for the same aim? I wouldn't like to use re.findall() function :)

Comment: @MaxU And how can you arrange your code to get only three output files? Is that possible? Thanks.

Comment: @erhan, then you would have to explain how do you want to write, for example, 5 founded occurrences into 5 files - what is the rule?

Comment: @MaxU I would like to have only three output files without using re.findall() function. That function makes me so confused. I hope you can help me?

Comment: @erhan, you didn't explain how would you like to distribute 4-5 blocks into 3 files or you are absolutely sure that you will always have only 3 blocks in your input file?

Comment: @MaxU I would like to distribute one block into each output file. I have more than 100 blocks but I need to first three blocks.

Comment: @erhan, so block#4 would go to file#1,  block#5 will go to file#2, etc. ?

Comment: @MaxU No, block#1 would go to file#1, block#2 would go to file#2 and block#3 would go to file#3.

Comment: @erhan, I've updated my "re.findall()" answer, so that it will write only first 3 blocks and will add another version without RegEx's bit later...

Comment: @erhan @MaxU  this adds a new line at the beginning of the second and third files and what is the purpose of the `write_blk` ?

Answer (score 3):

Read your input file and write to an output each time you find a "$$" and increase the counter of output files, code :

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    buff = []
    i = 1
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():  #skips the empty lines
           buff.append(line)
        if line.strip() == "$$":
           output = open('%d.txt' % i,'w')
           output.write(''.join(buff))
           output.close()
           i+=1
           buff = [] #buffer reset
```

EDIT: should be efficient too https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation

Comment: .@maazza your code gives this error:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "split.py", line 8, in <module>
    buff.append(line)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the condition that you should be checking for is a `line` that contains just the carriage return (`\n`) character. When you encounter such a `line`, write the contents of the parsed file so far, close the file, and open another one for writing.

Comment: Each character in the input will have a carriage return

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't explicit enough. I meant a `line` that contains _just_ the carriage return character.

Answer (score 0):

open `1.txt` *in the beginning for writing*. Write each line to the current output file. Additionally, if `line.strip() == '$$'`, close the old file and open a new one for writing.

Answer (score 0):

The blocks are divided by empty lines. Try this:

```
import sys

lines = [line for line in sys.stdin.readlines()]
i = 1
o = open("1{}.txt".format(i), "w")
for line in lines:
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
        o.close()
        i = i + 1
        o = open("{}.txt".format(i), "w")
    else:
        o.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way would if you want to split it in 2 files for example:

```
with open("myInputFile.txt",'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

with open("OutputFile1.txt",'w') as file:
    for line in lines[:int(len(lines)/2)]:
        file.write(line)

with open("OutputFile2.txt",'w') as file:
    for line in lines[int(len(lines)/2):]:
        file.write(line)
```

making that dynamic would be:

```
with open("inputFile.txt",'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

Batch = 10
end = 0
for i in range(1,Batch + 1):
    if i == 1:
        start = 0
    increase = int(len(lines)/Batch)
    end = end + increase
    with open("splitText_" + str(i) + ".txt",'w') as file:
        for line in lines[start:end]:
            file.write(line)
    
    start = end
```

Comment: The best solution so far