# Split Text Based on Symbol into Multiple Files with Python

Tags: split, python-3.7

I have a very long text file that I want to split into smaller files. It looks like:***200302 abcdfg ***200303 fasafafd ***200304 dajhskjsd

I want that the contents between *** are saved as a new file of the type (1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt...)

I have tried without success the suggestions posted in another discussion thread ([How can I split a text file into multiple text files using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916503/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-into-multiple-text-files-using-python))

I have also tried to use the code below which showed error.The error is in line 6 (SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character).

```
with open ('filename.txt','r') as fo:

    op=''
    start=0
    cntr=1
    for x in fo.read().split(*\n*):
        if (x=='***'):
            if (start==1):
                with open (str(cntr)+'.txt','w') as opf:
                    opf.write(op)
                    opf.close()
                    op=''
                    cntr+==1
            else:
                start=1

        else:
            if (op==''):
                op = x
            else:
                op=op + '\n' + x

    fo.close()
```

Comment: _I have also tried to use the code below which showed error._ --> Please [edit] your question and add the complete error that you get. Please do this always when you ask such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PLEASE! NEXT TIME ADD THE ERRORS THAT YOU GET TO YOUR QUESTION!**

First of all, there are two syntax errors in your code:

```
for x in fo.read().split(*\n*): # It's not *\n* but '\n'!
```

and

```
cntr+==1 # It's += !
```

These are easy to spot when you **read the error messages carefully!**

When you fix these errors your code will run but it will omit the last line of your file!

I assume that your file looks like this:

```
***  
200302 abcdfg 
***  
200303 fasafafd  
***
200304 dajhskjsd
```

So to get the last line too just add an if at the end (btw: no need for parenthesis in such simple ifs):

```
with open ('filename.txt','r') as fo:

    op=''
    start=0
    cntr=1
    for x in fo.read().split("\n"):
        if x=='***':
            if start==1:
                with open (str(cntr)+'.txt','w') as opf:
                    opf.write(op)
                    opf.close()
                    op=''
                    cntr+=1
            else:
                start=1

        else:
            if not op:
                op = x
            else:
                op=op + '\n' + x

    if start == 1 and op:
        with open (str(cntr)+'.txt','w') as opf:
            opf.write(op)
            opf.close()
            op=''
            cntr+=1


    fo.close()
```

This can also be simplified to

```
with open ('filename.txt','r') as fo:

    start=1
    cntr=0
    for x in fo.read().split("\n"):
        if x=='***':
            start = 1
            cntr += 1
            continue
        with open (str(cntr)+'.txt','a+') as opf:
            if not start:
                x = '\n'+x
            opf.write(x)
            start = 0
```

No need for `.close()` when you are using `with`!
And I'm pretty sure that you can simplify this even more.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Next time I will surely add the error description in the message. I tried to run the code above and an error appears for line 5 (for x in fo.read()...)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Next time I will surely add the error description in the message. I tried to run the code you suggested above and an error appears for line 5 (for x in fo.read()...) The error description is long, but the last line of the error description says: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x97 in position 10: invalid start byte". Please let me know if you have any suggestions to solve this.

Comment: Of yourse I have a suggestion: Use the correct encoding of your file when you open it, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699367/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte and lots of other questions for that error here on SO. Or convert your text file to utf-8 if that is possible :)